# Matplotlib - Adding quadrants to a strikezone?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a baseball analytics project and would like to display information based on the location of pitches over the course of a season to certain batters. While I can group the data points based on their location, I would like to display this in the form of a strikezone heatmap.

```
# define the strikezone quadrants 

# define our quadrents 

yTikMarks = [] 
feet = 1.6
while feet <= 4: 
    yTikMarks.append(feet)
    feet += round((2.1)/3, 2) 
    
xTikMarks = []
feet = -0.7 # from pitchers POV
while feet <= -0.7 + 1.4: 
    xTikMarks.append(feet) 
    feet += round((1.4)/3, 2) 

plt.figure() 
plt.xlim((-2,2))
plt.ylim((0,6))

# draw the plots 

rect = mpatches.Rectangle((-0.7,1.6),1.4,2.1, 
                        fill = False,
                        color = "black",
                        linewidth = 2)

plt.gca().add_patch(rect)

#plt.plot([xTikMarks[0],xTikMarks[0]],[yTikMarks[0],yTikMarks[3]], linewidth=4, color='red' )


print(yTikMarks)
print(xTikMarks)
```

yTikMarks and xTikMarks are the distances I would like to draw lines at to make the split the strikezone into 9 smaller squares. Is there an easier way to go about this?

I am considering moving over to R for this, but I would love to continue to use my pandas dataframes for calculations and information.

Thanks,
Cole

Comment: you need to provide as much code to make this reproducible on our end.

Answer (score 0):

I would do some of the calculations slightly different, but just working off your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

yTikMarks = [] 
feet = 1.6
while feet <= 4: 
    yTikMarks.append(feet)
    feet += round((2.1)/3, 2) 
    
xTikMarks = []
feet = -0.7 # from pitchers POV
while feet <= -0.7 + 1.41: 
    xTikMarks.append(feet) 
    feet += round((1.4)/3, 2) 


    

plt.figure() 
plt.xlim((-2,2))
plt.ylim((0,6))

# draw the plots 
for x in xTikMarks:
    color = 'red'
    line = 4
    if xTikMarks.index(x) == 0 or xTikMarks.index(x) == len(xTikMarks)-1:
        color = 'black'
        line = 2
    x1 = x
    y1 = yTikMarks[0]
    x2 = x
    y2 = yTikMarks[-1]
    plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], linewidth=line, color=color)

for y in yTikMarks:
    color = 'red'
    line = 4
    if yTikMarks.index(y) == 0 or yTikMarks.index(y) == len(yTikMarks)-1:
        color = 'black'
        line = 2
    x1 = xTikMarks[0]
    y1 = y
    x2 = xTikMarks[-1]
    y2 = y
    plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], linewidth=line, color=color)
```

**Output:**

[image]